# C++Builder not showing functions in Structure View panel

Tags: c++builder

The list of functions is not shown in Structure View panel by Embarcadero's C++Builder.

It is empty even when I create a new project.

[image: Structure View panel is empty in C++Builder]

I tried to find some setting in the Tools|Options menu, but I could not find it. 
What setting should I change?

I use C++Builder XE.

Comment: Something very obvious that I almost dare not write it, but have you checked that the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom is over to the left (and not fully over to the right, thus hiding the structure entries, unless they are long).

Comment: @RogerCigol Definitvelly, the scroll bar is at the left.

Comment: do not use namespace like c++17(namespace A::B{ ...}); try to imbricate namespaces( namspace A{ B{...}}); that worked for me!